# Getting span tag value into text box using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to get `<span>` tag value in to text.

Here is what I tried:

```
<span id="spanval">Hello</span>

<input type="text" name="username" id="name" value="">
```

jQuery:

```
var hi = jQuery("#spanval").text();
$("#name").val(hi);
```

How can I get value of span into text box?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mattii/z5de0Ljs/59/)

Comment: This is working well in your Fiddle if the missing jQuery is included: https://jsfiddle.net/ngjL47d5/

Comment: what;s wrong with my code?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your code. In your Fiddle you forgot to include jQuery which is needed for your code to work. You can download jQuery from here https://jquery.com/download/ or include a cdn hosted jQuery from e.g. here https://code.jquery.com/

Comment: i want to complete this question please post ANSWER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Fiddle you forgot to include jQuery which is needed for your code to work. You can download jQuery from [here](https://jquery.com/download/) or include a cdn hosted jQuery from e.g. [here](https://code.jquery.com/). Here is your code with included jQuery and it's working as expected.

```js
var hi = jQuery("#spanval").text();
$("#name").val(hi);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="spanval">Hello</span>
<input type="text" name="username" id="name" value="">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use vanilla Javascript as jquery is not included

Html

```
<span id="spanval">Hello</span>
<input type="text" name="username" id="name" value="">
```

Javascript

```
var hi = 
document.querySelector("#spanval").innerHTML; 
document.querySelector("#name").value = hi;
```

Comment: Try Now i mistakenly put () at innerHTML , now it is working fine

Answer (score 1):

**You can choose one of the available JQuery version from dropdown options in Fiddle**

[image: You can add JQuery from given options in fiddle]